# Wpf auto selection radio button and combox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 4 radio buttons that every one of them shows a different list in a combobox that attached to them. The radio button should be available only after pressing a some button. I want one of the radio button to be chosen and than the last row on the combo list to be chosen automatically.

MAINWINDOWS.XAML

```
<!--RadioButtons-->
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonA" GroupName="Button" Content="A"  Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Click="RadioButtonA_Click" />
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonB" GroupName="Button" Content="B" Margin="0,20,0,0" Grid.Column="0"  Click="RadioButtonB_Click"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonC" GroupName="Button" Content="C" Margin="0,35,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Click="RadioButtonC_Click"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonD" GroupName="Button" Content="D" Margin="0,50,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Click="RadioButtonD_Click"/>

<!--ComboBox-->
<ComboBox  
    x:Name="ComboBox"  
    IsEnabled="false" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Width="240"  
    Height="30" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,8,0,0"
    SelectionChanged="ComboBoxSelectionChanged" >
</ComboBox>
```

ViewModel: Example for one of the radiobuttons

```
private void RadioButtonA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IdComboBox.SelectedValue = string.Empty;
    IdComboBox.IsEnabled= true;
    IdComboBox.Items = AList;
    currentIdentifier = Identifier.A;
}
```

Comment: You need to include more information.  You say, "the radio button should be available only after pressing a some button."  What button?  Are _all_ the radio boxes unavailable until a single button is clicked?  If you can describe in more detail what behavior you want, we'll be able to better help you.  It'd be even better if you could create a mock-up image of what you want.

Comment: You need to press a button and only than the radio buttons should be enable. 1. pressing a button.2. radio buttons enabled. 3. one of the radio buttons is chosen already and the checkbox last row is chosen.

Comment: This question appears to be missing a [mcve] and has been abandoned, so ought to be put on hold for now.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "ViewModel", but you actually don't use MVVM.
Using event handlers to set state of many related controls is a doomed way - because complexity increases in proportion to the square of the amount of controls. You have to use MVVM, the approach when properties of controls are projected to a property of a model. Then you can use triggers to set controls state depending on the model property values. Or, if you consider triggers too verbose, you can use [QuickConverter](https://quickconverter.codeplex.com/), this library helps to simplify code.
Even if you don't like/cannot use any of them, please, use triggers to set state of comboboxes.